# Angular Material sidenav with submenu does not push properly when scrollbar visible

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I am using Angular Material sidenav and my menu has a sub menu.  When I open the sub menu a scrollbar appears making the sidenav slightly larger and it covers some of the main content.

See this Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raedvz, expand the sub menu and you will see the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Angular Material will only resize the container on nav.open, window.resize or on a mode change of the nav. You either have to trigger the resize of the container yourself or you could use the built in option `autosize`. But they tell you to use it at your own risk because it could cause performance issues.

`<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" *ngIf="shouldRun" autosize>`
Example on your stackblitz: https://angular-wsvjf8.stackblitz.io

I tested is in your example provided and it does work for me. If you get performance issues cause your app is doing lots more than just the example (obviously) you might have to trigger the resize yourself on your `toggleMenu` method.

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#resizing-an-open-sidenav

---

Update on your comment:

Im not sure whether this is the correct way or not. Based on what I can find in the code for the `autosize` option. What they do is check the margins every change detection cycle, which is why it could cause performance issues using the `autosize` option.
Afterwards, they call the private function `_updateContentMargins` and correct the margins of the container.

You could use a `ViewChild` and access the MatSidenavContainer and call that function in your `toggleMenu`. But since the `_updateContentMargins` function itself is private, I wouldn't use it.
Personally I can't think of another way of doing this.

Here's a working example of calling `_updateContentMargins` within your `toggleMenu`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-segnwt

I'm using `setTimeout` here as _ngZone of MatSidenavContainer was also made private now.

Comment: Thank you Agash!  I can get it to work in the stackblitz but you are right, I do need to trigger the resize myself in my app.  I am not sure how to do this.  Will you show me the command?  Reading the documentation I cannot find where they are doing something like this in typescript.  It all seems to be in the html.  Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. For others:  I 1. added #sideNavContainer to the html element,  2. added @ViewChild(MatSidenavContainer) sidenavContainer : MatSidenavContainer;  to the component  and 3.  this.sidenavContainer.autosize = true; to the component.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the autosize option anyways I would use it in the HTML directly, i don't see any benefits in setting it in your logic. I edited my comment to show you a way to trigger the resize manually, tho I wouldn't recommend it. I would use the `autosize` option right in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `autosize` attribute should fix your problem. Though that seems to have a performance impact.

Have a look at this github issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9601